# How to upload a 360º photo to Facebook using restfb?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I have a 360º jpeg file that works fine if upload to Facebook using its regular page.

When I try to upload the same file using restfb the image becomes "flat".

Does anybody know something specific to make it work with restfb?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you tried the additional parameter `allow_spherical_photo`?

Comment: @Norbert, I did, and it worked! You could write it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks @JonnyHenly. I will do better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the additional parameter `allow_spherical_photo=true`.